# What did I do wrong in my custom view to cause it to not be rendered in my expandable list view (other views render fine) - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create an expandable listview in Android that that uses a custom UI component as the childview but I'm having trouble actually getting it to render. When tracing my app with the debugger, I see that my custom UI object is instantiated and data is set but it seems like its then not added to the view even though I am returning the view at the end of `getChildView()`.

My ultimate goal is to make a custom UI element, `ServiceSelectionCheckbox`, that I can drag and drop directly from the layout pallete.

I tried inflating the XML for this component directly to see if it was my XML that had an issue that was causing a silent failure but it seems to inflate fine. I also have tried creating a secondary simpler UI component with a solid background to see if I can get that to add properly which it does fine. This leads me to think that my issue is with my custom UI component, `ServiceSelectionCheckbox.java` but I can't seem to figure out what that issue is. My linter throws no errors and my apk compiles fine.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> hashMapOfServices = new HashMap<>();
    public ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> aList;
    public ExpandableListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aList = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
        aList.add(new Pair<>("Men's Haircut", "50.00"));
        hashMapOfServices.put("Haircut", aList);
        list = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter((ExpandableListAdapter) new ServiceExpandableListAdapter(this, this.hashMapOfServices));


    }
}
```

This is my custom adapter

**ServiceExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
public class ServiceExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> hashmap;
    Context mContext;
    String[] selectedCategories;

    TextView price;
    ImageButton increment, decrement;
    ConstraintLayout lowerLayout;
    public static final ArrayList<String> POSSIBLECATEGORIES = new ArrayList<>(Collections.unmodifiableList(
            Arrays.asList("Barber", "Braids", "Children", "Color", "Esthetician",
                    "Eyebrows", "Eyelashes", "Hair Extensions", "Haircut", "Make-Up",
                    "Massage", "Nails", "Natural Hair", "Straightening", "Style", "Tanning", "Twists", "Waxing", "Weaves")));

    public ServiceExpandableListAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> data) {
        mContext = context;
        hashmap = data;
        selectedCategories = data.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);

    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalater.inflate(R.layout.group_heading, null);
        }
        TextView categoryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.service_category_tv);
        ImageView groupHolder = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupholder);
        categoryName.setText(selectedCategories[groupPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false);
            //This one works properly
//            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, parent, false);
        }

        //return convertView;

        String category = selectedCategories[groupPosition];
        ServiceSelectionCheckbox checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.service_selection_checkbox);

        String service = hashmap.get(category).get(childPosition).first;
        checkbox.setText(service);
//        Pair of format <ServiceName, Price>
        Pair<String, String> testPair = new Pair<>(hashmap.get(selectedCategories[groupPosition]).get(childPosition).first, hashmap.get(selectedCategories[groupPosition]).get(childPosition).second);
        if (hashmap.containsValue(testPair)) {
            checkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {

            checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {

        return this.hashmap.keySet().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return hashmap.get(selectedCategories[groupPosition]).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return hashmap.get(selectedCategories[groupPosition]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return hashmap.get(selectedCategories[groupPosition]).size();

    }

}
```

Here is the Java file for the custom UI element.

**ServiceSelectionCheckbox.java**

```
public class ServiceSelectionCheckbox extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ConstraintLayout lowerLayout;
    private ImageButton increment, decrement;
    private float price;
    private int quantity;
    private TextView priceView, quantityView;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private boolean isQuantitySelectionVisible;

    public ServiceSelectionCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String serviceName, String price, int quantity) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.isQuantitySelectionVisible = true;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_selection_checkbox_layout, null);
        priceView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.service_selection_priceview);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_checkbox);
        lowerLayout = (ConstraintLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_constraint_layout_quantity);
        quantityView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_service_quantity_countview);
        increment = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_increase_service_count);
        decrement = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_decrease_service_count);

    }

    public ServiceSelectionCheckbox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.init();
    }

    public ServiceSelectionCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.init();
    }

    private void init() {

        this.isQuantitySelectionVisible = false;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_selection_checkbox_layout, null);
        priceView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.service_selection_priceview);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_checkbox);
        this.setOnClickListener(this);
        lowerLayout = (ConstraintLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_constraint_layout_quantity);
        quantityView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_service_quantity_countview);
        increment = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_increase_service_count);
        decrement = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ssc_decrease_service_count);
    }

    public ServiceSelectionCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.init();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        isQuantitySelectionVisible = !isQuantitySelectionVisible;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        //set lowerlayout as visible based on visible variable
        if (this.isQuantitySelectionVisible) {
            lowerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            lowerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return super.performClick();
    }


    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.priceView.setText(String.valueOf(price));
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity);

    }

    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        this.checkBox.setChecked(b);
    }

    public void setText(String serviceName) {
        this.checkBox.setText(serviceName);

    }


}
```

And here is the corresponding XML files.

**group_heading.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/service_category_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Categoy"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/groupholder"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/groupholder"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/service_category_tv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the file that I believe is actually giving me problems.

**child_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <com.example.gabriel.uitest.ServiceSelectionCheckbox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/service_selection_checkbox"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Rendered on its own, the view is created as expected.
**service_selection_checkbox_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ssc_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Service"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ssc_constraint_layout_quantity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/service_selection_priceview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ssc_constraint_layout_quantity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ssc_checkbox">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ssc_decrease_service_count"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ssc_service_quantity_countview"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ssc_service_quantity_countview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ssc_increase_service_count"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ssc_decrease_service_count"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ssc_increase_service_count"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ssc_service_quantity_countview"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the test view component that I added for test purposes mentioned earlier, this one works fine.
**view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </View>
```

Comment: The way you are creating custom view is not right. After seeing your xml I assume you are trying to create compound view .. your custom view should extend Constraint layout and directly call inflate.. I assume layout by default will have inflate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your custom view as mentioned below.Add your other codes to this view. I am keep it simple so that it will be easier for you to understand.

```
public class CustomView extends ConstraintLayout {
        public CustomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }

        public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            init();
        }

        void init() {
            inflate(getContext(), R.layout. service_selection_checkbox_layout, this);
        }
    }
```

Dont nest constraint layout unless its required. In the above xml you given with one constraintlayout itself you can create the same UI.